# How can I use a website I made, offline and reconnect to local files instead of files on the google drive?

Tags: web, offline

I made a website that links to files loaded on google drive. Its a basic website and you can navigate to different sections and then access pdf files and images that are stored on a google drive. I need to figure out a way to make this be usable offline. I was thinking of just copying the whole website to a thumbdrive. However I dont know a way to make the external google files work offline. Is there a easy way to do this?

Comment: You can use a tool like wget.  There are lots of pages that explain how: https://www.google.com/search?q=wget+backup+website

Comment: I'm sorry to sound like a bother, but is there a better and easier to use software that I can use as an alternative to wget?

Comment: Just to followup - I use HTTrack and Cyotek to download the entire website to my harddrive. However links to google drive files dont work, or they have not been downloaded. Is there anyway to fix this?